# docker tensorflow linking with folder

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow

I am trying docker for tensorflow on windows 10 education, I have installed docker successfully and could run/ pull/ import images. I linked my docker container using

```
C:\User\xyz_folder> docker run -it tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-devel

root@23433215319e:~#cd /tensorflow

root@23433215319e:/tensorflow#git pull

From https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow
 * [new tag]         v1.11.0    -> v1.11.0
Already up-to-date.
```

Until here it ran fine without error. Following is the problem:

```
root@23433215319e:/tensorflow# cd abc_folder
bash: cd: abc_folder: No such file or directory
```

the abc_folder is there in linked folder but can not be seen in when it list it using 'ls'

```
root@23433215319e:/tensorflow#ls
ACKNOWLEDGMENTS  CODEOWNERS      LICENSE     WORKSPACE           bazel-out         configure.py  tools ADOPTERS.md      CODE_OF_CONDUCT.md  README.md    arm_compiler.BUILD  bazel-tensorflow  models.BUILD AUTHORS CONTRIBUTING.md     RELEASE.md   bazel-bin     bazel-testlogs    tensorflow BUILD  ISSUE_TEMPLATE.md   SECURITY.md  bazel-genfiles   configure    third_party
```

Please suggest how to link this properly so that I can see the shared folders content.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I am not mistaken you should check the -v flag for docker. Maybe this [blog](https://rominirani.com/docker-on-windows-mounting-host-directories-d96f3f056a2c) would help .

Answer (score 0):

To make a directory outside the container visible inside the container, you have to use the option -v or --volume as is stated [here](https://docs.docker.com/edge/engine/reference/commandline/run/#mount-volume--v---read-only).

So, your command would have to be:

```
docker run -v c:\local\directory:container/directory -it tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-devel
```

Whit that, you should be able to see the directory inside the container

Comment: I used the following but still no luck: $docker run -it --rm -v c:\dir:/tmp tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-devel root@123:~#tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-devel root@123:~# cd /tensorflow root@123:/tensorflow# ls ACKNOWLEDGMENTS CODEOWNERS LICENSE WORKSPACE bazel-out configure.py tools ADOPTERS.md CODE_OF_CONDUCT.md README.md arm_compiler.BUILD bazel-tensorflow models.BUILD

Comment: I think you ar mixing up the tags over there. Each tag mus be declared with its on respective value. For example: `docker run --rm -v c:\dir:/tmp -it tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-devel`.

If you declare all at the same time it dosen't work